# How to I get file from rails config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to open a file but I want to get that file from the app config. Is this possible? Right now I am getting the file directly from the controller.

This is how I am getting the file in the controller:

```
File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'dir', 'file.example')
```

I want to be able to do something like `ENV['file']`

Comment: Is `ENV['file']` an absolute path? If so, I don't see why `File.join` is necessary. Why not just use it directly in the controller (if you're sure this is something you really want to do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it on config.yml for example:

```
'file': 'app/dir/file.example'
```

When you want to set a file in `config.yml`, it looks for it from the rails root.